# Xtext: How to get from an object it's all text including it's formatting

Tags: java, xtext

I am trying to get the text of an object including it's formatting.
I tried to use something like this:

```
    EObject object = getObject(i);
    INode node = NodeModelUtils.getNode(object);
    data += NodeModelUtils.getTokenText(node);
```

But if I have the object written like this:

```
gar modeDoesNotChange:
  G mode=next(mode);
```

I get the text without the "/n" or "/t" like this: `gar modeDoesNotChange: G mode=next(mode);`

How I can get the text with all the new lines and the formatting?

(I am trying to get some objects from a file and to write it to a new file)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the text including hidden tokens (usually whitespace and comments), you should use `INode#getText()`.